# How do I make it so that certain animations play when a key is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it so that when you walk, a walking animation plays. When you are standing still, the idle animation plays. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it. (The character is called "Mr Man")

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MrManMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    private float moveInput;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(moveInput * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, moveInput * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D));
        {
            Mr Man.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Walk S");
        }

    }
}
```

It's telling me that there is a ; expected on line 26, and also a ',' is expected on line 26.

Comment: Line 20 must be where the if statement is. Remove the semicolon at the end of the if statement; they aren't supposed to be terminated with one.

Comment: My bad, I meant line 26, not 20.

Comment: Either way, does removing the semicolon fix the problem?

Comment: No, I did it and nothing changed

Comment: Regarding `Mr Man.GetComponent<Animator>()` - `Mr Man` is not a valid variable name because it is separated by white space. It also doesn't seem to be declared anywhere. More likely you meant `this.GetComponent<Animator>()` or more simply `GetComponent<Animator>()` omitting `this.`. As for actual animation, go read the Unity docs on the `Animator` component and then come and ask a question if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems I see there. First off, the condition will not fire. Well, it will, but any statement branched off it is ignored and ran anyway.

`if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D));`

The problem here is the semicolon. Remove it.

Next, this is an issue: `Mr Man.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Walk S");`

You can't have spaces in your variable names. Just remove **Mr Man.** and it shound work:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Walk S");
```

Braces are not required for just one instruction inside a branched condition.

Next, let's discuss optimizations and code review.

## moveInput

`private float moveInput;` to be exact.
Unless you use it in multiple functions, it has no place here, but rather a local variable inside `Update()`.
Also, saying "it works" or "it's the same thing" is not a correct approach.

## Caching old values

Considering players might idle, it's better to have a class-level variable of `oldHorizontal` and `oldVertical` that hold the previous value and then check if `moveInput` is different to the `old*` vars.

An example is this:

```
public class MrManMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float oldHorizontal = 0.0f; // assign to 0.0f by default !!!

    void Update()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    
        if (moveInput != oldHorizontal)
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(moveInput * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
            oldHorizontal = moveInput;
        }

        // rest of code
    }
}
```

## GetComponent()

Instead of using `GetComponent()` every single frame, a reference is more suitable, considering nothing changes. If the value of the variable is the same, cache it.

An example is this:

```
public class MrManMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // some code

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && (animator != null))
             animator.Play("Walk S");
    }
}
```

## Unnecessary calculations

I am referring here to `transform.position`.
Calculate both x and y on the same go, don't make multiple lines. You can save them to different local vars if you want readability.

## Formatting

Put a space between `if` and the condition for readability.

## Dependencies and bloating

Since you don't use them, delete these imports:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```